# How to patch a Class called in a task queue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, patch

Application:- Flask
Python:- 3.6.7
Test framework:- PyTest

I have a generic method defined in the following name space and has the following structure

```
my_app.contrib.util.request.GenericRequest
```

```
class GenericRequest:


    def __init__(self, method, url=REDIRECT_URL, **kwargs):

        self.method = method
        self.url = url
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def send_request(self):

        if self.method == "head":
            self.kwargs.setdefault("allow_redirects", False)

        with Session() as session:
            return session.request(method=self.method, url=self.url, **self.kwargs)
```

Im calling this method class from a celery task queue as follows which has the following namespace

```
my_app.task_queue
```

```
@app.task
def call_remote(**kwargs) -> str:

    response = GenericRequest(
            method="post",
            url=remote_app_url,
            timeout=10,
            params={
                "type": 10
            },
            headers=headers,
            cert=ca_file,
        ).send_request()

        if response.status_code == 200:
            remote_message = (response.json()["message"])
```

And I want to Mock `GenericRequest` from a pytest

Tried patch and failed and its not patching `GenericRequest`

```
def test_get_remote_message(client: Client) -> None:

   // more code here

    with patch("my_app.task_queue.GenericRequest") as mock:
        instance = mock.return_value
        instance.send_request = {"message": ""}
        for url in urls:
            client.post(url) # This will call the task queue's GeneriRequest
```

Also tried with the following namespace `my_app.contrib.util.request.GenericRequest` and got failed. How to mock GenericRequest which is being called from a task_queue via PyTest

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using `monkeypatch` which comes with `pytest`

Comment: Have to patch an object which is active in another process from one process, monkeypatch didnt work